# Nonlinear optimization using Google Apps Script for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to **maximize the value in a given Google Sheets cell** (let it be A2), by changing the value of a second cell (let it be A1). A2 is a non-linear function of A1. The dependency is complex and defined by several operations executed within the spreadsheet. **Is there a way of using Apps Script to solve the problem (and find a local maximum)?** I don't want to use existing add-ons.

Example:

```
A1 = 2
B1 = 2
A2 = IF(A1 < 5; A1^3 + B1^2; 0)
```

Expected optimization output:

```
A1 = 4
A2 = 68
```

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but Google Apps Script is really just an implementation of Javascript, so you could come up with a recursive function that modifies the input values, stores the output values, and compares the output values to determine the maximum